# How to reduce the size of the executable?

Tags: c++, gcc, executable, fmt

When I compile this code using the `{fmt}` lib, the executable size becomes 255 KiB whereas by using only `iostream` header it becomes 65 KiB (using GCC v11.2).

`time_measure.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "core.h"
#include <string_view>

int main( )
{
    // std::cout << std::string_view( "Oh hi!" );
    fmt::print( "{}", std::string_view( "Oh hi!" ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my build command:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG time_measure.cpp -I include format.cc -o runtime_measure.exe
```

Isn't the `{fmt}` library supposed to be lightweight compared to `iostream`? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Edit: By adding `-s` to the command in order to remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable, it becomes 156 KiB. But still ~2.5X more than the `iostream` version.

Comment: I don't think it will do much but replace "core.h" with <format>, only include what you use.

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer You mean the header which was added in C++20? But I want to replace `cout` with `fmt::print` which might perform a bit faster.

Comment: It is about minimizing the code you include "core.h" could include a lot more then what you actually need. By including <format> you only include the header file you actually need to compile your code. In this case your code should compile if you only include <format> (which if I am right includes string_view for you since it exposes that as part of its api)

Comment: A lightweight library doesn't necessarily mean "smaller executable size".   It can also refer to reduced memory usage or CPU cycles at runtime (for a similar observable effect) - things that might be achieved but also increase executable size - or anything else that is in the mind of the developer who produced it.   In any event, the specifics as to one library or another results in a larger/smaller executable depend on many factors.

Comment: @Peter **As you can see, {fmt} has 60% less overhead in terms of resulting binary code size compared to iostreams and comes pretty close to printf.** This is written in https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/README.rst

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with any other library there is a fixed cost and a per-call cost. The fixed cost for the {fmt} library is indeed [around 100-150k](https://www.zverovich.net/2020/05/21/reducing-library-size.html) without debug info (it depends on the compiler flags). In your example you are comparing this fixed cost of linking with the library and the reason why iostreams appears to be smaller is because it is included in the standard library itself which is linked dynamically and not counted to the binary size of the executable.

Note that a large part of this size comes from floating-point formatting functionality which doesn't even exist in iostreams (shortest round-trip representation).

If you want to compare per-call binary size which is more important for real-world code with large number of formatting function calls, you can look at object files or generated assembly. For example:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  fmt::print("Oh hi!");
}
```

generates (https://godbolt.org/z/qWTKEMqoG)

```
.LC0:
        .string "Oh hi!"
main:
        sub     rsp, 24
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        xor     edx, edx
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     rcx, rsp
        mov     esi, 6
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp], xmm0
        call    fmt::v8::vprint(fmt::v8::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v8::basic_format_args<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >)
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

while

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Oh hi!";
}
```

generates (https://godbolt.org/z/frarWvzhP)

```
.LC0:
        .string "Oh hi!"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edx, 6
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
```

Other than static initialization for `cout` there is not much difference because there is virtually no formatting here, so it's just one function call in both cases. Once you add formatting you'll quickly see the benefits of {fmt}, see e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0645r10.html#BinaryCode.

Comment: What if I build {fmt} as a shared lib and then use it? Will it reduce the binary size? Will I be able to run the program on another computer? Or will it require access to the shared library?

Comment: @digito_evo it will require access to the shared library libfmt.so. Just like the iostreams variant needs access to libstdc++.so in a compatible version. The difference might be that you'll have libstdc++.so anyway.

Comment: note that you want to ship your tool to some other computer, you'll either need to ship all the libraries it uses (including x86_64 2.2 MB libstdc++.so and then libfmt.so contributes some rather tiny 150 kB) or you need to statically link, in which I'm not convinced using iostreams isn't worse in terms of size.

Comment: @Marcus Müller What exactly is static linking? How should I do that?

Comment: @digito_evo pretty big question, I'm sure you'll find documentation about that on the internet in masses, but if you read some documents and can't fully understand them, don't hesitate to open a new question!

Answer (score 3):

You forget that iostreams is already included in the stdlibc++.so that is not counted towards the binary size since it is a shared library (usually). I believe by default fmt is built as a static library file so it increases the binary size. You need to compile fmt as a shared library with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE` as explained in [the building instructions](https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html#building-the-library)

Comment: So this will reduce the binary size?

Comment: Are you building the fmt library or you're including from a distro?

Comment: I just included the `core.h` from its folder. I have downloaded the zip file from their website.

Comment: Yes but only on disk. Once it's brought into memory it will link with the shared library anyway.

Comment: I want the size of the binary to be small. So this means that I need to use CMake to build fmt library and then use it in my code?

Comment: There are several methods of building fmt as a library, as you can see in that page above. CMake is one of them. Can I ask you why your binary size has to be small?

Comment: I'm writing a small sandbox app. I want it to be tiny and optimized (90KiB to 110 KiB) and not larger.

Comment: Well you will be just moving code from the binary to a shared library. The size in memory will be virtually the same.

Answer (score 0):

in your build/link command, why don't you use -Os option (Optimize for size) ?

Comment: That won't make a huge difference though.